# How to enable xdebug in php.ini?

Tags: php, xdebug, pecl

I am trying to install `xdebug` as explained [here](http://xdebug.org/docs/install), but unfortunately the instructions are flawed. After I have done

```
pecl install xdebug
```

there was no file

```
/usr/local/php/modules/xdebug.so
```

So is there an easy way to find the location of this file for inclusion in the `php.ini` file, or so I have to search the entire filesystem myself?

Comment: Usually one does _not_ install such packages that way. Use your software management system of your distribution instead, that has many advantages. Amongst others you can ask it what files are contained in a package.

Comment: Hmm, installing with `apt-get` seems to work. Without having to manually edit some config files. Thank you very much...

Comment: Sure, you are welcome. Keep in mind: a wild installation is _always_ a bad idea. You never know what that tool does, what is happening, that is flying in the dark. And you do it with `root` priviledges!